# oauth2 login : shows says Unauthorized - unable to generate access_token

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am getting below error when i hit the endpoint `http://localhost:8078/auth/slogin` from POSTMAN.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")      
public class AuthenticationController {


   @PostMapping("/slogin") 
   private String loginUser() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
       try {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       String clientId = "fooClientIdPassword";
       String clientSecret = "secret";
       String encodedData = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary((clientId + ":" + clientSecret).getBytes("UTF-8"));
       String authorizationHeaderString = "Authorization: Basic " + encodedData;

       HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8078/oauth/token");
       List<org.apache.http.NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<org.apache.http.NameValuePair>();
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "fooClientIdPassword"));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "secret"));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "ashu@gmail.com"));  
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "ashutosh"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8)); 
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
        post.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeaderString); 
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
       String body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 

        return body;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

   }
}
```

if i pass the above parameter and hit the auth server URL `http://localhost:8078/oauth/token` directly from POSTMAN then it works, it gives access_token .

So if am hitting the url `http://localhost:8078/oauth/token` through above java code does not works. It shows 
`{"timestamp":"2019-10-24T05:29:29.566+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/oauth/token"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change `String authorizationHeaderString = "Authorization: Basic " + encodedData;` to `String authorizationHeaderString = "Basic " + encodedData;`

I think the problem is that your post request give a wrong format authorization header.

your authorization header: `authorization: Authorization: base64_string`

the right header: `authorization: Basic base64_string`